How to manage tensor in mathematica
I open this topic because I would like to ask the community how to handle this tensor sum regarding solid mechanics.
I apologize if what comes next will generate some confusion, but I am new to using mathematica and am just learning.
In particular we see on the left a 4-order tensor as a sum of tensors of order 4 and 6 and the derivatives of the displacements "u" with respect to a reference system whose coordinates are given by ξ= ξ1 ξ2 ξ3. Moreover, u depends on the coordinates and also on time.
And u = (u1, u2, u3)

These are all elastic tensors, also there are different indices and each index varies from 1 to 3.
Taking the second term in which there is the derivative of the displacements uγ with respect to the coordinate ξρ, it is to set that when γ is equal to a certain index then it must take the component of u related to the index that comes from γ.
The same for the third member of the formula to the right of equal.
Eεη, on the other hand, is the infinitesimal strain tensor.
What I would like to ask is whether there is a way to render this in symbolic form and subsequently apply precise values to the components of the tensors that are inside.
For example, Cαβγδ on the right should have the form of an isotropic bond with blade constants, as in the second picture.
The latter I found by assigning an array, in which I assigned the components, and then running the Arrayreshape command to find it in tensor form.

But maybe it could also result from a shape like the one in the third image:

Question:
How is it possible to create the tensor C as a function of the four variables afore mentioned? Such that I can operate standard tensor calculus with its specified terms i.e. C1121 + C1232
Thank you all for your help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
